# Add vertical spacing between MUI Select components

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to use MUI to create a vertical stack of [Select](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/) components, but they appear without any spacing between them:

[image: demonstration of spacing issue]

The group is wrapped in a `Box` and each control looks like this:

```
<FormControl key={i} fullWidth>
     <InputLabel id={`select-label-${i}`}>{mux}</InputLabel>
     <Select
          labelId={`select-label-${i}`}
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
     >
        {/* items omitted */}
     </Select>
</FormControl>
```

When I look at the [Sign In template](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/v5.8.3/docs/data/material/getting-started/templates/sign-in), the two `TextField`s have vertical spacing seemingly without having to do anything extra:

[image: template without the issue]

I have gotten reasonable results from using `display: "grid", gridTemplateRows: "repeat(auto-fill 1fr)"` on my parent `Box` but I don't know if this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with a [Stack](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stack/) component instead of a Box.

```
<Stack spacing={2}>
    ....
</Stack>
```